# Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported

Tags: android

Из-за 2 строки вот такая ошибка. Как устранить?

> The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
>   - Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported!

код:

```
<item name="android:shadowColor">@color/shadowColor</item>
<item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
<item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
<item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это проблемы Android Studio. Просто нажмите "Ignore".

Comment: Я так и делаю... Но просто каждый раз делать... То есть никак нельзя убрать?

Comment: @Omuradil, скорее всего, нет.